# How to restart dockerd?

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

#### Context

In my `.devcontainer` that, I run in GitHub Codespaces, I've installed `minikube`. Shortly after `minikube start` I get this message

```
Executing "docker container inspect minikube took an unusually long time: 10.566089734s*

Restarting the docker service may improve performance.
```

1. I'm using docker `docker-in-docker` feature.
2. The `.devcontainer` environment starts docker with [dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) cli.
3. `systemctl` is not present container running my environment

#### Question

I'd like to restart docker to improve performance. Is it possible to restart docker without stopping the `docked` process? Something like `sudo systemctl restart docker` but with `dockerd`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  "Restart Docker" on bare metal would normally imply stopping and recreating the `dockerd` process.  For things running in containers, you don't usually restart processes but rather delete and recreate the container; can you delete the DinD container?

Answer (score 1):

To restart `dockerd`, restart the `docker` service itself. For example, `sudo systemctl restart docker` in ubuntu.

Comment: Please note the third item from the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

My initial conditions were a little different yet I think the solution still applies here.

I was creating a `.devcontainer` with a `docker-in-docker` and `nvidia-cuda` features enabled. I could see the GPU in the dev container but it wasn't available to the container on the second level. For that, I needed to install `nvidia-container-toolkit` in the first level container.

Since `nvidia-container-toolkit` creates a new docker runtime, this requires a `dockerd` restart. Default instructions would achieve this via `sudo systemctl docker restart` command, however, due to space constraints, sometimes `systemctl` isn't available.

Like the OP, I also resorted to restarting `dockerd` by killing the process and starting it again.

In short, I've achieved this by adding the following line to my CUDA-enabled `devcontainer.json`:

```json
// Reload dockerd after installing the nvidia-container-toolkit.
"postCreateCommand": "sudo pkill dockerd && sudo pkill containerd && bash /usr/local/share/docker-init.sh",
```

Commands `sudo pkill dockerd` and `sudo pkill containerd` essentially terminate `dockerd` and `containerd` processes. `/usr/local/share/docker-init.sh` script was brought-in by `ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-in-docker` feature, so, if you're using it, you don't need to modify the command.

However, if not, you should replace `bash /usr/local/share/docker-init.sh` with `( dockerd > /tmp/dockerd.log 2>&1 ) &` to start `dockerd` process again.

Answer (score 0):

After careful studding of [dockerd cli](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/), I concluded that there is no other option of restarting the docekrd process than just killing it and starting it manually again.

Comment: I deleted the comment. But yes, you are right - I didn't read the question, only the answer. To kill the docker daemon, you need to get its ID. Use `ps aux | grep dockerd`  next `kill -9 DOCKERD_ID`. To start the docker daemon, manually run `docked` (you might run it in the background, not in the foreground, as [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/start/)  says). Please delete your comment too Thanks!